# Suggestions for Authenticating between applications (Salesforce ->Heroku)

Tags: java, rest, heroku, oauth, salesforce

I have been struggling over the past week to get the ideal configuration for my implementation. Basically, I have a Salesforce Page which makes a REST callout containing some data to be computed, A Heroku server then computes this data before sending the computed data back to SF in the response. This all happens in the background and so no Heroku front end exists.

I want to protect this callout with oAuth2, but I'm not sure the best way to do it:

The data itself is not important, its the access to the heroku app which is.

If I use salesforce for authentication, it means that the callout structure doesn't work (I would have to implement a system for Heroku to grab the data from SF before returning it) which isn't ideal and I can't see a way to use Heroku authentication as it allows access to the api but not the app script in a single structure. I think I have to create my own authentication server within Heroku but I'm not exactly sure if this is the correct way of going about it.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated

This is my callout code from SF:

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
//Sets the url to heroku
request.setEndpoint('My App URL');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
//places the content into the body
request.setBody(content);
//Extends the read timeout
request.setTimeout('120000');
//Sends the request and waits for a response
HttpResponse response;
response = http.send(request);
```

Heroku Side:

```
    post("/", (req, res) -> {
        //creates a local var for the JSON string
        String data = req.body();
        //--** The server then computes this data and calculates output
        String computedData = compute(data);
        return computedData;
    });
```

I need a way of authenticating this type of connection, Thanks!!!

Comment: Is your Salesforce app public facing? ie. can I (or more specifically the provider - Heroku) do a GET on your Salesforce app? This is key really to how the OAuth flow works.

Comment: Yes, I think so, once the user logs in through salesforce, which should already be logged in to be able to make the callout to begin with, the app can be accessed by going to the URL:https://c.eu11.visual.force.com/apex/MyAppName

Comment: Is the data in the Heroku app user specific? Is it that you want users (logged into your Salesforce app) to be able to authorize the Salesforce app  to access their data managed by the Heroku app? This is what AOuth is designed for ie. Authorization, not Authentication.

Comment: I think maybe what you are looking for is to authenticate your Salesforce app with your Heroku app - so that not just anyone can anonymously call your Heroku app?

Comment: Yes this is correct, what I am looking for is to authenticate so that no-one else can call Heroku except the intended user. I don't want Heroku to be able to access any salesforce data except the data passed through the callout, ie 'content' and Salesforce should only receive the data in a response from Heroku. This is why SF side Authentication won't work for me as I don't want Heroku to have to be able to grab the data from SF rather be sent it.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to add some logic to your Heroku app that only accepts incoming requests from your Salesforce host. Are you using SSL/TLS for the transaction? If so, you could send some client ID in the request as well as an extra layer of security.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about an implementation similar to this. I am not currently using any kind of security, only a simple HTTP callout. If I implemented TLS how would I ensure that the Heroku server checks for only the correct client ID without redirecting similar to oAuth?

Comment: So you pass an ID (could be just a hashed value) as a header - only your Salesforce App and Heroku App are aware of the ID. On the Heroku side you get the (decrypted) authentication header (for each request) and check that it matches what you expect. This assumes you are using HTTPS. If you can only use HTTP then you need to encrypt the ID (using a private key) before adding to Request Header (Salesforce) and decrypt (Heroku) using the public key of the pair.

Comment: Due to Heroku only allowing SSL if paid for, I have chosen to go for another route, any suggestions?

Comment: See last comment - you can encrypt an ID using a pair of keys. If you want something quick/dirty then why not just check the referrer Header in Heroku and if it is anything other than your Salesforce app then disallow it (return a 401 or 403)? Referrer is not completely reliable though so it depends on how much effort you want to put into your security.

Comment: After trying a range of options including the one you have stated, I feel as if the best course of action would be to implement my own, basic, 2-legged oAuth server using a similar encryption to what you have said.

Comment: Josh, OAuth is about users not needing to share passwords with clients (eg. Salesforce) who are trying to access their resources on a Service provider (eg. Heroku). It doesn't sound like you have this use case.Are you accessing user date in your Heroku app?

Comment: Yes I understand this, my implementation will simply be the client id, encrypted with the client secret, sent, then decrypted to verify, I will then generate an access code and use this within salesforce. Not an actual true oAuth implementation, but following a kind-of 2 legged oAuth implementation. This is as you suggested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the [Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oauth) to OAuth? It's pretty helpful. The flow would be:-

1. Salesforce app issues a redirect to your Heroku - `GET https://id.heroku.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={client-id}&response_type=code&scope={scopes}&state={anti-forgery-token}`
2. After user has authorized access there is a callback to your Salesforce app with an exchange token
3. You Salesforce app then needs to exchange the token for an Access token with your Heroku app with the relevant scopes to access the data at Salesforce

I'm not sure if this is what you want though since the whole point of OAuth is not authentication but authorization ie. the OAuth flow is not designed to identify the user, but to enable you client (Salesforce in this case) to access the user's resources held by the provider (your Heroku app in this case).

---

Since you want Authentication, not Authorization, there are a couple of approaches you could take depending on how much work you want to put in vs how secure it needs to be (you have to make a call on this).

1. Quick and dirty but not very secure

   You could just check the referrer Header on Heroku and if the client is anything other than your Salesforce app then you return a 403 Forbidden or 401 Unauthorized. It's not very reliable since referrer is not overly reliable but its quick and straightforward if you do not have a great understanding of authentication and just want something quick and basic.
2. Send a client ID with each request

   This could be a Header or be in the body of the request. For it to be secure though you will need to encrypt it since you say you do not want to use SSL/TLS. So you will need to encrypt/decrypt the client ID at each end.

   A basic approach is to just use some symmetric key that you share between your client (Salesforce) and provider (Heroku) which you store securely within each app somewhere so that hackers cannot read it. You also share (and securely store) some ID string (ideally some long random hash).

   The flow would go like this:-

   1. Salesforce app takes the random ID string and uses the symmetric key to encrypt it. This is what you send in the request to your Heroku app.
   2. Heroku app - on receiving an incoming request - reads the encrypted value. It then uses the symmetric key to decrypt it. Your Heroku app then compares the decrypted value passed in the request and the random ID string (it also has stored locally) and if they are the same you have some degree of confidence that the source of the request was your Salesforce app. If not you deny the request.

Authentication is a big subject, as is encryption. If you really need to protect the data and there is a risk of you being sued if you do not, then you need to do some more research. If the data is not sensitive (or particularly valuable to anyone else) and you are just trying to have some basic front gate which reduces other applications from exerting a load on your application then you could consider just checking the referrer as a first attempt.